# Plotting Minimize output for a range of constraint values

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

I want to plot the minimum of a function returned by **Minimize** over a range of constraint values.

```
Plot[Minimize[{2*Exp[-x] + 0.5*Exp[-y], x >= 0, y >= 0, x + y == z}, {x, y}], {z, 4, 20}]
```

This is the command I used: for a range of $z$, I wan to plot the minimum of this optimisation program. However I get no graph, though I get values for the Minimize command in isolation. How do I use plot appropriately here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the $x$ and $y$ values that minimize your function:

```
mydata = Table[
  {x, y} /. 
   Minimize[{2*Exp[-x] + 0.5*Exp[-y], x >= 0, y >= 0, x + y == z}, {x,
       y}][[2]], {z, 0, 3, .1}];
```

Here are the actual minima values of your function for the minimizing values of $x$ and $y$:

```
myminima = 2*Exp[-#[[1]]] + 0.5*Exp[-#[[2]]] & /@ mydata;
```

Here are the simple $z$ values in a range:

```
myzvalues = Table[z, {z, 0, 3, .1}]
```

Here is a plot of the minimum of your function for various values of $z$:

```
 ListPlot[Transpose[{myzvalues, myminima}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. No I want to plot the min value of the program as a function of $z$. It is $F(z)$ v $z$, where $F(z)$ is the value of the objective function at the $(x,y)$ that your table provides.

Comment: What [2] means in mydata?

Comment: The second (realistic) of the two solutions.