# Finding local minima of an energy defined by integration

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, mathematical-optimization

This question is also asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58383611/finding-local-minima-of-an-energy-defined-by-integration-in-mathematica) and [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1807029).

I would like to reproduce the two solid curves in Fig. 1a of [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a6c1/553c33b3f24e95ae0daf7799d51968ca48ee.pdf) paper. The total energy is given in Appendix A, and the curve is obtained by minimizing the energy with respect to the variational parameters $\sigma_k$ and $d$. I'm not sure what dimensionless variables they used on their code, but I'll expresses the energy using $(x,y,z)=(\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z)/\bar{a}$; $(wx,wy,wz)=(\omega_x,\omega_y,\omega_z)/\bar{\omega}$; $as=a_s/\bar{a}$ and so on (Notice that $\bar{a}$ has length dimension and $\bar{\omega}$ has the dimension inverse time).

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Idip[X_?NumericQ, Y_?NumericQ, u_?NumericQ] := Re[Exp[-u^2/2] - 
    3 X*Y/(1 - X^2)^(3/2) NIntegrate[
      v^2 Exp[-u^2 X^2 v^2/(2 (1 - X^2) (1 - v^2))]/(Sqrt[1 - v^2] Sqrt[1 - v^2 (1 - Y^2)/(1 - X^2)]), {v, 0, 
       Sqrt[1 - X^2]}]];

f[X_?NumericQ, Y_?NumericQ] := Re[Idip[X, Y, 0]];

Iqf[u_?NumericQ] := Re[2 Exp[-5 u^2/8]/Sqrt[Pi] NIntegrate[
     Exp[-l^2] Cosh[Sqrt[2/5] u*l]^(5/2), {l, 0, Infinity}]];

ettot[x_, y_, z_, u_, wy_] := h*w[wy]/Kb (1/4 (1/x^2 + 1/y^2 + 1/z^2) + 
     1/4 (wx[wy]^2 x^2 (1 + u^2/2) + wy^2 y^2 + wz[wy]^2 z^2) + 
     as[wy]*n/(2 Sqrt[2 Pi] (x*y*z)) (1 + Exp[-u^2/2]) + 
     add[wy]*n/(2 Sqrt[2 Pi] (x*y*z)) (-f[x/z, y/z] - 
        Idip[x/z, y/z, u]) + 512*Sqrt[2] as[wy]^(5/2) n^(3/2)/(75 Sqrt[5] Pi^(7/4) (x*y*z)^(3/2)) (1 + 
        3 add[wy]^2/as[wy]^2) Iqf[u]);
```

**Obs:**  In the code, $wx$ and $wz$ are dimensionless, but $wy$ has the dimension inverse time. Morover, since they have used Kelvin units, I divided the total energy by $Kb$.

In order to find the local minima I have used the following code based on the one found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207482/using-nminimize-with-table-to-plot-an-energy/207486#207486):

```
a0 = 5.29*10^(-11); (* Bohr radius *)
h = 1.054*10^(-34); (* Reduced Planck's constant *)
M = 163.9*1.66*10^(-27); (* Dy-164 mass in kg *)
wxx = 2 Pi*70; (* Experimental value of x-frequency *)
wzz = 2 Pi*1000; (* Experimental value of z-frequency *)
w[wy_] := (wxx*wy*wzz)^(1/3); 
a[wy_] := Sqrt[h/(M*w[wy])];
wx[wy_] := wxx/w[wy]; (* Dimensionless x-frenquency*)
wz[wy_] := wzz/w[wy]; (* Dimensionless w-frenquency*)
add[wy_] := 131*a0/a[wy]; (* Dimensionless Dipolar length*)
as[wy_] := 70*a0/a[wy]; (* Dimensionless contact length*)
n = 10^4;
Kb = 1.38*10^(-23); (* Boltzmann constant *)

   ddata1 = Table[minsol1 =FindMinimum[{ettot[x, y, z, 0, wy/w[wy]], 
      x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0}, {{x, 1.01}, {y, 1.012}, {z, 0.14}}, 
     Method -> Automatic, PrecisionGoal -> Automatic, 
     AccuracyGoal -> Automatic];
   Re[{x, y, z, wy/(2 Pi) , minsol1[[1]]} /. Last[minsol1]], {wy, 
    2 Pi*100, 2 Pi*250, 2 Pi*20}];

ddata2 = Table[minsol2 =FindMinimum[{ettot[x, y, z, d/x, wy/w[wy]], 
      x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 && d > x}, {{x, 1.01}, {y, 1.012}, {z, 
       0.14}, {d, 1.02}}, Method -> Automatic, 
     PrecisionGoal -> Automatic, AccuracyGoal -> Automatic];
   Re[{x, y, z, d, wy/(2 Pi) , minsol2[[1]]} /. Last[minsol2]], {wy, 
    2 Pi*100, 2 Pi*250, 2 Pi*20}];

ListPlot[{ddata1[[All, {4, 5}]], ddata2[[All, {5, 6}]]}, 
 Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic}]
```

I get two pretty nice curves using this code. However, I expected the curves to match at $f_y = 200$ Hz Moreover, at $f_y < 200$ Hz it had to be negative. Could helpe me?

[image]

**Additional comment:** There is probably an error in the paper, since neither Figure 1a nor Figure 6a can be obtained from the total energy. This is very strange, however, because the group is well respected in the area. Anyway, should I send an email to authors asking about it? They used probably C++ instead of Mathematica.

Comment: Recommend that you use `NumericQ` rather than `NumberQ`. Try `(# /@ {2, 2., Pi, E, x} )& /@ {NumberQ, NumericQ}`

Comment: @BobHanlon I tried, but I'm still having trouble.

Comment: The comment was not intended to resolve your problem. Recommend that you proof-read your code. For example, the definition for `Idip` uses `X` and `Y` on the LHS but `x` and `y` on the RHS.

Comment: Thank you anyway.

Comment: I updated my question!

Comment: There are many more errors. For instance, you define a function `add[yw_]` but inside `ettot` you simply use it as symbol `add` without arguments. Same for `as` and `wz`. I'm not even sure how you could calculate any results at all :)

Comment: @halirutan I I forgot to fix that. I Fixed it now. But my original code had already been fixed.

Comment: Please copy your code into Mathematica and verify that it is syntactically correct. For instance, there is `(2 Pi])` in your code (a line starting with `Re`) which cannot be correct.

Comment: @halirutan Thanks again for your help. It it fixed now.

Comment: @DineshShankar  Why did you expect that `ddata1[[All, {4, 5}]], ddata2[[All, {5, 6}]]` should match when $f_y=250 Hz$? In Fig. 1, the curves intersect at $f_y=200$

Comment: @AlexTrounev You're right. Fixed now.

Comment: @DineshShankar You use a different function $E_{tot}$ than in the article.

Comment: @AlexTrounev You're sure? The energies has the same structure. I just use dimensionless variables. Notice that there is a typo in the article. Variable $\bar{a}$  must be in units of length. My definition of this variable is right.

Comment: @DineshShankar If there is one typo, then it is possible there is another.

Comment: @AlexTrounev It's  possible. But putting the ansatz A1 into the energy functional 2.22 of their Phd thesis [here](https://www.pi5.uni-stuttgart.de/documents/abgeschlossene-arbeiten/2018-Wenzel-Matthias-Macroscopic-States-of-Dipolar-Quantum-Gases-PhD.pdf) I have  found the energy expression written above.  By the way, this paper is dicussed in chapter 4 of the phd thesis.

Comment: Should I send an email to authors asking about it? But I guess they used C++ instead of Mathematica.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After studying the article and theses, as well as article [Ground-state properties and elementary excitations of quantum droplets in dipolar Bose-Einstein condensates](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.08676v1.pdf)
 from which the ansatz was taken, I came to the conclusion that the ansatz may not have been calibrated to find the magnitude of the energy. Therefore, we calibrate the ansatz using the data in Fig. 1:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

Idip[X_?NumericQ, Y_?NumericQ, u_?NumericQ] := 
  Re[Exp[-u^2/2] - 
    3 X*Y/(1 - X^2)^(3/2) NIntegrate[
      v^2 Exp[-u^2 X^2 v^2/(2 (1 - X^2) (1 - v^2))]/(Sqrt[
           1 - v^2] Sqrt[1 - v^2 (1 - Y^2)/(1 - X^2)]), {v, 0, 
       Sqrt[1 - X^2]}]];

f[X_?NumericQ, Y_?NumericQ] := Re[Idip[X, Y, 0]];

Iqf[u_?NumericQ] := 
  Re[2 Exp[-5 u^2/8]/Sqrt[Pi] NIntegrate[
     Exp[-l^2] Cosh[Sqrt[2/5] u*l]^(5/2), {l, 0, Infinity}]];

ettot[x_, y_, z_, u_, wy_] := 
  h*w[wy]/Kb (1/4 (1/x^2 + 1/y^2 + 1/z^2) + 
     1/4 (wx[wy]^2 x^2 (1 + u^2/2) + wy^2 y^2 + wz[wy]^2 z^2) + 
     as[wy]*n/(2 Sqrt[2 Pi] (x*y*z)) (1 + Exp[-u^2/2]) + 
     add[wy]*n/(2 Sqrt[2 Pi] (x*y*z)) (-f[x/z, y/z] - 
        Idip[x/z, y/z, u]) + 
     512*Sqrt[
       2] as[wy]^(5/
         2) n^(3/2)/(75 Sqrt[5] Pi^(7/4) (x*y*z)^(3/2)) (1 + 
        3/2 add[wy]^2/as[wy]^2) Iqf[u]);
a0 = 5.29*10^(-11);(*Bohr radius*)h = 
 1.054*10^(-34);(*Reduced Planck's constant*)M = 
 163.9*1.66*10^(-27);(*Dy-164 mass in kg*)wxx = 
 2 Pi*70;(*Experimental value of x-frequency*)wzz = 
 2 Pi*1000;(*Experimental value of z-frequency*)
w[wy_] := (wxx*wy*wzz)^(1/3);
a[wy_] := Sqrt[h/(M*w[wy])];
wx[wy_] := wxx/w[wy];(*Dimensionless x-frenquency*)
wz[wy_] := wzz/w[wy];(*Dimensionless w-frenquency*)
add[wy_] := 131*a0/a[wy];(*Dimensionless Dipolar length*)
as[wy_] := 70*a0/a[wy];(*Dimensionless contact length*)n = 10^4;
Kb = 1.38*10^(-23)*10^-9(*nK*);(*Boltzmann constant*)ddata1 = 
 Table[minsol1 = 
   FindMinimum[{ettot[x, y, z, 0, wy/w[wy]], 
     x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0}, {{x, 1.01}, {y, 1.012}, {z, 0.14}}, 
    Method -> Automatic, PrecisionGoal -> Automatic, 
    AccuracyGoal -> Automatic];
  Re[{x, y, z, wy/(2 Pi), minsol1[[1]]} /. Last[minsol1]], {wy, 
   2 Pi*100, 2 Pi*250, 2 Pi*20}];

ddata2 = Table[
   minsol2 = 
    FindMinimum[{ettot[x, y, z, d/x, wy/w[wy]], 
      x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 && d > x}, {{x, 1.01}, {y, 1.012}, {z, 
       0.14}, {d, 1.02}}, Method -> Automatic, 
     PrecisionGoal -> Automatic, AccuracyGoal -> Automatic];
   Re[{x, y, z, d, wy/(2 Pi), minsol2[[1]]} /. Last[minsol2]], {wy, 
    2 Pi*100, 2 Pi*250, 2 Pi*20}];
```

Compose a new ansatz $E_{total}=k E_{tot}+b$ and find the constants $b,k$

```
et1 = Interpolation[ddata1[[All, {4, 5}]]]; et2 = 
 Interpolation[ddata2[[All, {5, 6}]]];

sol = NSolve[{b1 + k1 et1[200] == b2 + k2 et2[200], 
   b1 + k1 et1[160] == 0, b2 + k2 et2[144] == 0, 
   b2 + k2 et2[220] == 20}, {b1, b2, k1, k2}]
```

Now we optimize a new ansatz

```
{b2, k2} = First[{b2, k2} /. sol]

ddata2 = Table[
   minsol2 = 
    FindMinimum[{b2 + k2 ettot[x, y, z, d/x, wy/w[wy]], 
      x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0 && d > x}, {{x, 1.01}, {y, 1.012}, {z, 
       0.14}, {d, 1.02}}, Method -> Automatic, 
     PrecisionGoal -> Automatic, AccuracyGoal -> Automatic];
   Re[{x, y, z, d, wy/(2 Pi), minsol2[[1]]} /. Last[minsol2]], {wy, 
    2 Pi*100, 2 Pi*250, 2 Pi*20}];

{b1, k1} = First[{b1, k1} /. sol]

ddata1 = Table[
   minsol1 = 
    FindMinimum[{b1 + k1 ettot[x, y, z, 0, wy/w[wy]], 
      x > 0 && y > 0 && z > 0}, {{x, 1.01}, {y, 1.012}, {z, 0.14}}, 
     Method -> Automatic, PrecisionGoal -> Automatic, 
     AccuracyGoal -> Automatic];
   Re[{x, y, z, wy/(2 Pi), minsol1[[1]]} /. Last[minsol1]], {wy, 
    2 Pi*100, 2 Pi*250, 2 Pi*20}];
```

Finally, build the curves and plot the data. It looks similar to Fig. 1, but there are differences in curvature. Note that you can not do re-optimization, because the data of re-optimization accurately lie on the curves obtained in the first optimization
[image: Figure 1]

Comment: This is a pretty nice answer. But let me ask you one quick question regarding your answer. It is possible only because you habe already knowed  some information about the original Figure, is it?

Comment: @DineshShankar We can use numerical data obtained by solving the equation (1). It is only necessary to determine the shift and the intersection point $f_y=200$ Hz.This is determined from an experiment I think.

Comment: I got it! Thank you for your help.

Comment: @DineshShankar You're welcome!